# Get Jenkins filtered job param value using xpath

Tags: jenkins

I have the below xml from the jenkins job data. I am trying extract the  value for the selected name **yaml_data** inside the paramters..

I am using below url to filter the data but it still lists all the name and value of the parameters.

```
https://jenkins.myorg.com/job/architecture-shared-services/job/nyjobdata/lastBuild/api/xml?tree=actions[parameters[name[contains(text(),yaml_data)],value]]
```

```
<workflowRun _class="org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.job.WorkflowRun">
    <action _class="hudson.model.ParametersAction">
        <parameter _class="hudson.model.TextParameterValue">
            <name>yaml_data</name>
            <value>mycoredatahere</value>
        </parameter>
        <parameter _class="hudson.model.TextParameterValue">
            <name>artifact_no_ext</name>
            <value>../pom</value>
        </parameter>
        <parameter _class="hudson.model.TextParameterValue">
            <name>artifact_repository</name>
            <value>myorg-io-maven-hosted</value>
        </parameter>
        <parameter _class="hudson.model.TextParameterValue">
            <name>release</name>
            <value>build</value>
        </parameter>
        <parameter _class="hudson.model.TextParameterValue">
            <name>build_name</name>
            <value>maven</value>
        </parameter>
</action>
</workflowRun>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@ycr has provided the correct answer, this just expands a bit more information based on the above question

You were nearly there, but your request is asking to display the tree: `/xml?tree=`

What you actually want to request is the parameter tag with its values from the xml api where the parameter name has a specific text by using xpath as you noted in the question, so that should be: `/xml?xpath=`

Append the url filter after api with:

```
/xml?xpath=//parameter[name[contains(text(),%27yaml_data%27)]]
```

(where %27 is the unicode character for apostrophe - so essentially you are sending this : `'yaml_data'`)

the result returned should be the following:

```xml
   <parameter _class="hudson.model.TextParameterValue">
       <name>yaml_data</name>
       <value>mycoredatahere</value>
   </parameter>
```

You're full url query based on the above question will be:

```
https://jenkins.myorg.com/job/architecture-shared-services/job/nyjobdata/lastBuild/api/xml?xpath=//parameter[name[contains(text(),%27yaml_data%27)]]
```

If you want the value only, then add a `/value` at the end of the query, the result returned should be the following:

```xml
       <value>mycoredatahere</value>
```

You're full url query will be:

```
https://jenkins.myorg.com/job/architecture-shared-services/job/nyjobdata/lastBuild/api/xml?xpath=//parameter[name[contains(text(),%27yaml_data%27)]]/value
```

Answer (score 2):

Try the following URL and the Xpath.

```
https://jenkins.myorg.com/job/architecture-shared-services/job/nyjobdata/lastBuild/api/xml?xpath=//parameter[name='yaml_data']/value
```

Comment: Yes this is plain and neat :)